# How to create relation between user and table without User table

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I'm creating a weather app for Android. I use a local database, SQLite, with room. And I'm wondering how to create a One-to-One relation between a User and a favorite location. As I consider authentication in the weather app to be pointless, I gave up on creating the entity 'User'. I've created an entity called Search History (Which seems to be a one-to-many relation), which gives hints to the user based on his recent searches.

```
@Entity(tableName = "search_history")
public class SearchHistoryEntry {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public int id;
    public String cityName;
    public String date;

    public SearchHistoryEntry(String cityName, String date) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Now I'm wondering how to create a one-to-one relationship between a user without a physical user entity and a favorite location.

Maybe I should create a table user with only user_id in it?

Comment: What does your DB table look like If it has a user just add a field Favorite Location and let the user select how to view data Fav Loc or your other option

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want this favourite to persist?

- If so then it will have to be stored somewhere; database or perhaps shared preferences.

Could it perhaps simply be the most prevalent CityName in the search history, if so it would not need to be stored anywhere as a query could obtain the most used/prevalent CityName.

**Database (Room) solutions**

If the former and the database then a single column single row table could be utilised.

Perhaps something like

```
@Entity
public class TheOneAndOnlyFavourite {
    @PrimaryKey
    String cityName;
    .... constructors, getters and setters
}
```

The issue comes with either maintaining a single such value or determining which value of many is the required favourite CityName, for example when and if the favourite is to be changed.

- Note you should use `@Insert(onConflictStrategy = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE`) to prevent issues should an attempt be made to insert the same CityName (the UNIQUE conflict, as a Primary Key is implicitly UNIQUE, will then be ignored as opposed to resulting in an exception).

You could maintain just a single row by inserting once and then subsequently updating (noting that you could not utilise the Room convenience `@Update` as the primary key is used to identify the row to be updated, if changed then nothing will be updated). You would need to use an `@Query("UPDATE TheOneAndOnlyFavourite SET cityName=:newCityName;")`

You could have many rows and select the latest inserted based upon the normally hidden **rowid** that would exist. Using something like `("SELECT * FROM TheOneAndOnlyFavourite ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1")`.

- Obviously as time goes by more rows may be added, so this may have an impact upon the size of the database. However, a table is allocated chunks (pages) of storage (default is 4k) and a table has at least 1 such page. So just having the table will consume 4k which could hold quite a few rows before another 4k is required.

Having the favourite as this table means that it could be used as the criteria for selection of the favourites without the need to get the favourite as a value to then be passed to the query to select the favourites from the SearchHistory.

**Demonstration**

Using your SearchHistoryEntry class plus:-

```
@Entity
public class TheOneAndOnlyFavourite {
    @PrimaryKey
    @NonNull
    private String cityName;

    TheOneAndOnlyFavourite(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }

    public String getCityName() {
        return cityName;
    }

    public void setCityName(String cityName) {
        this.cityName = cityName;
    }
}
```

and:-

@Dao
abstract class AllDAOs {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
abstract long insert(TheOneAndOnlyFavourite theOneAndOnlyFavourite);
@Insert
abstract long insert(SearchHistoryEntry searchHistoryEntry);

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM theoneandonlyfavourite ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1")
abstract String getTheFavouriteCityName();

@Query("UPDATE theoneandonlyfavourite SET cityName=:newFavourite WHERE rowid = (SELECT min(rowid) FROM theoneandonlyfavourite)")
abstract int updateFavourite(String newFavourite);

@Query("SELECT * FROM search_history WHERE cityName = (SELECT cityName FROM theoneandonlyfavourite)")
abstract List<SearchHistoryEntry> getSearchesAccordingToFavourite();

@Query("WITH cte as (SELECT *, count(*) AS n FROM search_history GROUP BY cityName) SELECT cityName FROM cte ORDER BY n DESC LIMIT 1")
abstract String mostPopularSearch();

@Query("SELECT * FROM search_history WHERE cityName = (SELECT cityName FROM TheOneAndOnlyFavourite ORDER BY rowid DESC LIMIT 1)")
abstract List<SearchHistoryEntry> getSearchesAccordingToTheLatestFavourite();
```

}

and:-

```
@Database(entities = {SearchHistoryEntry.class,TheOneAndOnlyFavourite.class},version = 1,exportSchema = false)
abstract class TheDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    abstract AllDAOs getAllDAOs();

    private static volatile TheDatabase instance;

    static TheDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance==null) {
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context,TheDatabase.class,"the_database.db")
                    .allowMainThreadQueries() /* for brevity */
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

And to demonstrate the above following activity code:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TheDatabase db;
    AllDAOs dao;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this);
        dao = db.getAllDAOs();
        SearchHistoryEntry currentSH = new SearchHistoryEntry("","");

        /* Add some Search Histories */
        for(int i=0;i < 5; i++) {
            for (int ii = 0; ii < 10-i; ii++) {
                String dayofmonth = String.valueOf(ii);
                if(ii < 10) dayofmonth = "0" + String.valueOf(ii);
                currentSH.cityName = "CN" + String.valueOf(i);
                currentSH.date = "2024-01-" + dayofmonth;
                dao.insert(currentSH);
            }
        }
        /* Get the most prevalent */
        String mostPrevalentCityName = dao.mostPopularSearch();
        Log.d("DBINFO","Most Prevalent City Name is " + mostPrevalentCityName);
        /* Set most prevalent as favourite to demonstrate the TheOneAndOnlyFavourite */
        dao.insert(new TheOneAndOnlyFavourite(mostPrevalentCityName));
        /* Extract the searches for the favourite city */
        for (SearchHistoryEntry sh: dao.getSearchesAccordingToFavourite()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","SH ID is " + sh.id + " City is " + sh.cityName + " Date is " + sh.date);
        }
        /* Change the Favourite */
        Log.d("DBINFO","Changing the favourite city name to CN003");
        dao.updateFavourite("CN3");
        /* Extract the searches for the favourite city */
        for (SearchHistoryEntry sh: dao.getSearchesAccordingToFavourite()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","SH ID is " + sh.id + " City is " + sh.cityName + " Date is " + sh.date);
        }

        /* Add some more favourites */
        dao.insert(new TheOneAndOnlyFavourite("NOT A CITY SEARCHED"));
        dao.insert(new TheOneAndOnlyFavourite("ANOTHER NOT A CITY SEACHED"));
        dao.insert(new TheOneAndOnlyFavourite("CN2"));

        for (SearchHistoryEntry sh: dao.getSearchesAccordingToTheLatestFavourite()) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","SH ID is " + sh.id + " City is " + sh.cityName + " Date is " + sh.date);
        }
    }
}
```

**Results**

The log (first run as it's just to demonstrate) includes:-

```
2024-01-05 16:50:19.979 D/DBINFO: Most Prevalent City Name is CN0
```

- as expected CN0 is the most prevalent (10 rows)

Then after insert the fav as CN0 :-

```
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 1 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-00
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 2 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-01
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 3 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-02
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 4 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-03
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 5 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-04
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 6 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-05
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 7 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-06
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 8 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-07
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 9 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-08
2024-01-05 16:50:19.988 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 10 City is CN0 Date is 2024-01-09
```

Change fav to CN3 and (the 7 rows expected):-

```
2024-01-05 16:50:19.989 D/DBINFO: Changing the favourite city name to CN003
2024-01-05 16:50:19.993 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 28 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-00
2024-01-05 16:50:19.993 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 29 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-01
2024-01-05 16:50:19.993 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 30 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-02
2024-01-05 16:50:19.993 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 31 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-03
2024-01-05 16:50:19.993 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 32 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-04
2024-01-05 16:50:19.994 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 33 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-05
2024-01-05 16:50:19.994 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 34 City is CN3 Date is 2024-01-06
```

After inserting some favs (couple if useless ones), the last added being CN2, then (8 rows) :-

```
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 20 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-00
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 21 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-01
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 22 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-02
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 23 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-03
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 24 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-04
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 25 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-05
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 26 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-06
2024-01-05 16:50:20.016 D/DBINFO: SH ID is 27 City is CN2 Date is 2024-01-07
```

So multiple rows in the TheOneAndOnlyFavourite can be handled by using the latest added (according to the rowid).

- **but** not if the attempt where to insert using a cityname that has been previously used (simple enough to handle e.g. empty the table before the insert).